# C/C++ пустой va_list равен 20 (переменное количество аргументов)

Tags: c++, c, функции, системное-программирование

[image]

Проблема: Если передается только один аргумент (int chr[]), то factor равен 20. Это плохо, так как 20 - потенциальный аргумент :)

Заранее спасибо

Comment: 1. Вторым параметром `va_start` должен быть `chr`, а не `0`. 2. Нельзя дергать `va_arg`, если в `...` вы передали ноль параметров.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно передавать длину как ещё один параметр. Узнать кол-во параметров, которые есть в va_args [похоже нельзя](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598132/length-of-va-list-when-using-variable-list-arguments).

Может использовать vector?

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать

Comment: А за что же минус?

Comment: Можно пользоваться трюком, которым пользуются функции типа `printf()`. Второй вариант, как это сделано в Gtk+, последний, незначащий параметр всегда NULL.

Comment: можно. Все эти варианты сводятся к тому, что кол-во элементов нужно знать. Тем или иным способом.